# exchanging variables between virtual keyboard page to other opened page in javascript only (NOT Jquery)?

Tags: javascript, html

I have crossword puzzle page (that called puzzle.aspx), that i've created.

Every time the client press on table data its open up a new window page (that called keyboard.aspx) with the id of the table data within query string(for example: keyboard.aspx?0_8 then the location is row 0 column 8).

The problem is i dont know how to pass from the keyboard.aspx the letter the client pressed on back to the open page???

Answer (score 1):

When you're in popup, you can access page that opened popup via `opener` keyword. So, for example if opener page has `function acceptLetter()` you can call it from the popup as `opener.acceptLetter()`.

Knowing this you can follow these steps.

1. In the opener page define function `acceptLetter(position, letter)` it will accept "row_column" position and letter pressed by the client.
2. In the popup when client pressed the letter - call that function as `opener.acceptLetter` and pass, as parameters, position (which you already know from query string) and letter pressed.

For example if popup is opened as "keyboard.aspx?0_8" and client pressed letter "W" you will call the function as `opener.acceptLetter('0_8', 'W');`. Also, I assume after letter is pressed, popup is no longer needed, so after above call, make a call to `window.close();` to close the popup.